# PowerShell: Combine two hash tables

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have two hash tables created from data from two different XML files.  What I would like to do is combine the two tables into a single hash table based on a common value in the both tables.

Inv Hash:

```
    $invHash = $invXML.InventoryDto.ProductInventoryItem.SkuInventoryItem | 
select @{ L = 'SkuID'; E = { $_.SkuId } }, @{ L = 'SkuStatusCode'; 
E = { if ($_.SkuStatusCode -eq 'Active') { 'True' } else { 'False'} } }, 
@{ L = 'QuantityOnHand'; E = { $_.QuantityOnHand } }
```

Sample Contents of $invHash:

```
SkuID    SkuStatusCode    QuantityOnHand 
-----    -------------    --------------  
1828     True             441 
3022     True             325 
2981     True             214 
2989     True             842
```

PriceHash:

```
    $priceHash = $priceXML.PricingDto.ProductPricingItem.SkuPricingItem | 
select @{ L = 'SkuID'; E = { $_.SkuId } }, @{ L = 'RegularPrice'; 
E = { $_.PriceGroup.RegularPrice } }, @{ L = 'CurrentPrice'; 
E = { $_.PriceGroup.CurrentPrice } }
```

Sample contents of $priceHash:

```
 SkuID    RegularPrice     CurrentPrice 
 -----    -------------    --------------  
 1828     49.99            48.99
 3022     25               19.99
 2981     45               39.99
 2989     28               18.99
```

Desired contents of $invpriceHash:

```
SkuID    SkuStatusCode    QuantityOnHand  RegularPrice     CurrentPrice   
-----    -------------    --------------  --------------  --------------
1828     True             441             49.99            48.99
3022     True             325             25               19.99
2981     True             214             45               39.99
2989     True             842             28               18.99
```

Comment: Seems to me that you are trying to perform an "in-memory join". This blog-post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/07/13/join-object.aspx has a comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given :

f1.csv is :

```
SkuID,SkuStatusCode,QuantityOnHand
1828,True,441 
3022,True,325 
2981,True,214 
2989,True,842
```

f2.csv is :

```
SkuID,RegularPrice,CurrentPrice
1828,49.99,48.99
3022,25,19.99
2981,45,39.99
2989,28,18.99
```

Try this *far-fetched* solution, not so good as `join-object` because you need to know the properties. You also have to be careful here with `+` operator between `$a` and `$b` which is not commutative it changes the group order :

```powershell
   $a = Import-Csv C:\temp\f1.csv
   $b  = Import-Csv C:\temp\f2.csv
   $b + $a | Group-Object -Property skuId  | 
% {$x= New-Object -TypeName psCustomObject -Property 
@{SkuID=$_.name;RegularPrice=$_.group[0].RegularPrice;
CurrentPrice=$_.group[0].CurrentPrice;
SkuStatusCode=$_.group[1].SkuStatusCode;QuantityOnHand=$_.group[1].QuantityOnHand};
 $x}
```

for me it gives :

```
QuantityOnHand : 441 
RegularPrice   : 49.99
SkuStatusCode  : True
SkuID          : 1828
CurrentPrice   : 48.99

QuantityOnHand : 325 
RegularPrice   : 25
SkuStatusCode  : True
SkuID          : 3022
CurrentPrice   : 19.99

QuantityOnHand : 214 
RegularPrice   : 45
SkuStatusCode  : True
SkuID          : 2981
CurrentPrice   : 39.99

QuantityOnHand : 842 
RegularPrice   : 28
SkuStatusCode  : True
SkuID          : 2989
CurrentPrice   : 18.99
```

Comment: This worked great!  Didn't realize that I was actually working with objects and not hashes.  Once I understood that it made this a lot more logical.