# Merging Two Csv's with the differnent properties

Tags: csv, properties, merge, powershell-3.0

I have two Csv's

Csv1
CI Name, region
xyz,London
abc,Cairo
lmn,Brisbane
qrs,Sao paulo

Csv2
DeviceName, IPAddress
abc, 10.0.0.1
xyz, 10.0.0.2
ijk, 10.0.0.3
lmn, 10.0.0.4

Desired output 
CI Name, Region, IPAddress
abc, Cairo, 10.0.0.1
xyz, London, 10.0.0.2
lmn, Brisbane, 10.0.0.4
ijk, ,10.0.0.3
qrs, Sao Paulo,

As you can see the property name CI Name and DeviceName is different of Csv 1 and csv 2 although there are common values

Other merge functions that I checked here have the same property name, for example CI Name or DeviceName is found on both CSVs
How would i do this? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A far as I understand you are looking for a way to join these two CSV tables on 'CI Name' = 'DeviceName' .

You can apply the answer of [PowerShell: Combine two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027718/608772).

The only you have to do is to change the way you import one of the CSV file :

```
Import-Csv 'Csv1.csv' -Header "DeviceName", "region" "xyz", "London abc", "Cairo lmn", "Brisbane qrs", "Sao Paulo"
```

Perhaps you have to remove the previous heaser first.