# MAP CSV userdata to separate CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, user-data

I have inherited a bit of a mess. I have multiple CSV Files with different user data. I need to find a way to compile all of the information together into one file, and I don't want to spend hours doing it. The problem is that not all of the users are the same, and they are not in the same order. Is there an easy way to pull fields from a second file to another where the username matches one in the first file? I am sure I'm not describing this correctly, just starting out.

For example:
File 1

```
username,first,last,phone number
john.do,John,Doe,8888675309
jack.jo,Jack,Johnson,5378984687
harry.po,Harry,Potter,9876543219
```

File 2

```
username,first,last,email
john.do,John,Doe,john.squidwork@yahoo.com
sandy.mi,Sandy,Michaels,sandy.mi@hotelcalifornia.com    
jack.jo,Jack,Johnson,bubbletoes@jackjohnson.net
harry.po,Harry,Potter,iluvmuggles@diagonalley.com
```

Comment: Personally, I'd probably import them into an SQL database and join the tables.  As it is, you might want to take a look at [Join-Object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/07/13/join-object.aspx).

Comment: I gave an answer of approximately   the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17027718/608772).

Comment: The blog about join-object just went on my favorites list. I intend to read and learn this.  The first part seems to be a review of first, second, and third normal forms, although it doesn't say so.  Thanks!

Comment: I have MS Access on one of my computers, and loading CSV files into access is like playing a video game.  Coming up with the correct joins is a little tougher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it as you will, this should combine multiple CSV files. Note that it may not be fast, but it should be thorough.

```
$CSVList = 'C:\Path\To\Users1.csv','C:\Path\To\Users2.csv','C:\Path\To\Users3.csv','C:\Path\To\Users4.csv','C:\Path\To\Users5.csv'
$PrimaryTable = @{}
Import-CSV $CSVList[0] | %{$PrimaryTable.Add($_.UserID,$_)}
$PrimaryKeys = $PrimaryTable.Values[0] | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
ForEach($CSVFile in ($CSVList|Select -Skip 1)){
    $Users = Import-CSV $CSVFile
    $Keys = $Users[0] | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    $KeysToAdd = @{}
    $Keys|?{$_ -notin $PrimaryKeys}|%{$KeysToAdd.Add($_,"")}
    $PrimaryTable.Values|%{$_|Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $KeysToAdd}
    ForEach($User in $Users){
        If(!($User.UserID -in $PrimaryTable.Keys)){
            $PrimaryKeys | ?{$_ -notin $Keys} | %{add-member -InputObject $User -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue ""}
            $PrimaryTable.Add($User.UserID,$User)
        }Else{
            $Keys | ?{[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($PrimaryTable.($User.UserID).$_)} | %{$PrimaryTable.($User.UserID).$_ = $User.$_}
        }
    }
    $PrimaryKeys = $PrimaryTable.Values[0] | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
}

$PrimaryTable.Values|Export-CSV C:\Path\To\AllUserData.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

That makes a hashtable indexed off the UserID. It populates it with the data from the first CSV file. Then for each additional one it checks the differences in properties of what's in the first CSV and the current one, adds the missing properties to all the items in the main hashtable, then goes entry by entry, and if the user isn't in the main hashtable it adds them, and if they are then it fills in any blanks that it can for their properties.

**Edit:** Ok, so you appear to be having issues with the `-notin` operator. The most likely reason for that is an older version of PowerShell. My first suggestion is to update to v3 or v4 of PowerShell, but I know that's not always an option, so to make this a little more backwards compatible I've made some edits to the script that should make it work for you... I hope. I did test the above script (with updated paths in line 1, and I commented out the last line because I didn't feel like littering my hard drive with yet more files) with 3 CSV files that all have the UserID field, and each had 2 to 4 entries, and it worked exactly like I expected it to. Anyway, the edited script is:

```
$CSVList = 'C:\Path\To\Users1.csv','C:\Path\To\Users2.csv','C:\Path\To\Users3.csv','C:\Path\To\Users4.csv','C:\Path\To\Users5.csv'
$PrimaryTable = @{}
Import-CSV $CSVList[0] | %{$PrimaryTable.Add($_.UserID,$_)}
$PrimaryKeys = $PrimaryTable.Values[0] | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
ForEach($CSVFile in ($CSVList|Select -Skip 1)){
    $Users = Import-CSV $CSVFile
    $Keys = $Users[0] | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    $KeysToAdd = @{}
    $Keys|?{$PrimaryKeys -notcontains $_}|%{$KeysToAdd.Add($_,"")}
    $PrimaryTable.Values|%{$_|Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $KeysToAdd}
    ForEach($User in $Users){
        If(!($User.UserID -in $PrimaryTable.Keys)){
            $PrimaryKeys | ?{$Keys -notcontains $_} | %{add-member -InputObject $User -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue ""}
            $PrimaryTable.Add($User.UserID,$User)
        }Else{
            $Keys | ?{[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($PrimaryTable.($User.UserID).$_)} | %{$PrimaryTable.($User.UserID).$_ = $User.$_}
        }
    }
    $PrimaryKeys = $PrimaryTable.Values[0] | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
}

$PrimaryTable.Values|Export-CSV C:\Path\To\AllUserData.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

That should do what you want, and should work in older versions of PowerShell. Let me know if you have errors with it. Again though, my recommendation is to update PowerShell if you are running v2. You will be happier in the long run than doing work arounds.

Comment: This sounds like it is exactly what I need! However when I update the paths and run it I get the following error: 

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At :9 char:17
+     $Keys|?{$_ - <<<<  notin $PrimaryKeys}|%{$KeysToAdd.Add($_,"")}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Comment: Hm, I copied and pasted it exactly as it is, updated paths in the first line, commented out the last line since I didn't want to output, and ran it, and it did exactly what it was supposed to with 3 short CSV files that I made just for testing (each had the UserID field, and 2 to 4 records to parse). **What version of PowerShell are you using?** Are you using PS v2? I don't think the `-in` and `-notin` operators were introduced until v3.

Comment: Alright, it took me a minute to realize what was going on. -in and -notin are not in Powershell 2.0. It worked fine once I updated Powershell. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is causing one problem for me. I think I may have found how to change the behavior though. The behavior in question is the addition of  userid's from the additional csv files. I have already gone through and removed obsolete users from my main file. When using this script like you mentioned it adds in users not present in the first file.
`ForEach($User in $Users){ If(!($User.UserID -in $PrimaryTable.Keys))` If I'm reading this correctly this adds the fields if the UserID already exists, is this correct? And the Else section adds them if the UserID does not exist?

Comment: Ok, the `If(!($User.UserID -in $PrimaryTable.Keys))` is what looks to see if the user is in the primary table. The line two below that which reads `$PrimaryTable.Add($User.UserID,$User)` is what actually adds the user. Comment that line out if you don't want to add users from the additional tables to the first one.

Comment: I thought I was blind for a second, I couldn't find that line in the file anywhere, I actually updated to powershell 3.0 so I'm using the original, which works wonderfully, but I'm still not sure which part is adding the users.

Comment: That didn't change between the 2.0 and 3.0 scripts. It is line 14 as seen in either of my scripts above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function, you can use to group data by some key. If some group will have multiple different values for some property, then resulting object will have array with all values for that property:

```
function Group-Data {
    param(
        [object[]]$Property
    )
    $AllProperties=[ordered]@{}
    @(
        $input|Group-Object $Property|ForEach-Object {
            $_.Group|ForEach-Object {$Properties=@{}} {
                $_.PSObject.Properties|Where-Object Value|ForEach-Object {
                    if($Properties[$_.Name]){
                        if($Properties[$_.Name]-notcontains$_.Value){
                           $Properties[$_.Name]=@($Properties[$_.Name];$_.Value) 
                        }
                    }else{
                        $Properties[$_.Name]=$_.Value
                        $AllProperties[$_.Name]=$null
                    }
                }
            } {[PSCustomObject]$Properties}
        }
    )|Select-Object @($AllProperties.Keys)
}
```

Here is a function, which join arrays in properties. You need to use it, because `Export-Csv` does not handle arrays in properties correctly.

```
filter Join-Array {
    param(
        [string]$Separator=', '
    )
    $_.PSObject.Properties|Where-Object Value -is Array|ForEach-Object {
        $_.Value=$_.Value-join$Separator
    }
    $_
}
```

And you can use it that way:

```
Import-Csv File1.csv,File2.csv,File3.csv|Group-Data username|Join-Array|Export-Csv Result.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Data management can be messy, especially when you inherit a mess, which is most of the time.

One of the best tools to help you manage data is a database management system, aka a DBMS.  That may, however be overkill in your case.  You may only need to do this operation once, until you have all the messy inherited data in one neat CSV file that you can keep up to date going forward.  In that case, the learning curve for a full blown DBMS may not be worth it.

There are three relational operators that give relational databases much of their power to process data at retrieval time.  These operators are restrict (formerly called select), project, and join. If you can mimic these three operators in PS, you may be able to clean up your data in PS without invoking a DBMS.

PS already has a good operator that does what restrict does.  It's where-object.

PS already has a good operator that does what project does.  It's group-object.

Relational join is where it gets messy.  As far as I know there is no join-object in PS.  However Bacon Bits provided a link to the [Join-Object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/07/13/join-object.aspx) blog article, and this appears to be exactly what is needed if you want to create a join-object function on your own.  Thanks, Bacon bits.  Some of the blog article is motivational, explaining why decomposing (splitting) tables is sometimes a good thing, and then motivating the join-object for use  when you want the data all in one place.  If you are an SQL jockey, you already know that stuff.  But learning how to do it in PS is great.

Comment: Well, we seldom clean out the barn for our successor, especially if we've just been fired after years of loyal service.